# Convert map viewport click position to map coordinates (Bing maps)

Tags: javascript, canvas, dictionary, bing-maps

So I have a `canvas` overlaid on a Bing JavaScript v7 map, and the idea is that when the user clicks on the canvas, it creates a pushpin in the map behind it at the same point.

However, in my current kludged-up code always places the pushpin in the wrong place. Fiddle for reference; http://jsfiddle.net/89SCq/2/

How can I fix the math to make this work? Note: I have to use an overlaid canvas rather than capturing click events directly on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you must use the canvas you can calculate the pixel coordinates clicked by the user on the canvas and then pass  these through the tryPixelToLocation method relative to the position of the map control. Here is an updated version of your click event:

```
$("canvas").click(function(e){
    var relativeX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var relativeY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    var loc = map.tryPixelToLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Point(relativeX, relativeY), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control);

    // push pin; location is top right corner in degs plus a portion of map degree dimension based on relative click pos
    map.entities.push(
        new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc, null)
    );

    // DEBUG; zoom out to show marker pos
    map.setView({ zoom: 9 });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a canvas? Why not just add a click event to the map like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function GetMap()
    {   
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), { 
            credentials: "YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY"
        });

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', addPushpin);
    }

    function addPushpin(e){
        var loc = map.tryPixelToLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
        map.entities.push(pin);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='myMap' style='position:relative;width:800px;height:600px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, I need to use a canvas. The fiddle is a demo environment that doesn't reflect my actual use case, but I still have this pixel-to-coordinate conversion problem.